# Vba separate multiple dates in one cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to separate multiple dates from one cell into multiple cells containing one date in a transposed area and then paste them back over the original area as separate entries.

An example cell might have dates stored like 10/1110/1110/13 or 10/310/310/410/5.
The second scenario is what is causing the error as there is no leading zero for single digit days like 10/3, for example.

Ideally, the code would separate the dates into separate cells like: 10/11,10/11,10/13 and 10/3,10/4,10/5. When single digits days are present ,however, it comes out completely jumbled up and inaccurate.

Admittedly, I had help from another coworker with this code who is on vacation currently, which is why I am having such trouble understanding this. Is there something I could change to account for single digit days or should I approach this process differently?

Thanks!

```
'separate column J by "/" and store in transpose area

  dim h as variant
  dim i as variant
  dim j as variant
  dim counter as variant
  dim stringcheck as variant
  dim strInput as variant
  dim strCurrent as variant



 strInput = Cells(j, 10)
 h = 0

For counter = 1 To Len(strInput) - 2
    stringcheck = InStr(strInput, "/")
    Debug.Print j & stringcheck
    If stringcheck <> 0 Then


        If Mid(strInput, counter, 1) = "/" Then
            Cells(17, i + h) = strCurrent & Mid(strInput, counter, 3)
            counter = counter + 2
            h = h + 1
            strCurrent = vbNullString
        Else
            Cells(17, i + h) = Cells(j, 10)
            strCurrent = strCurrent & Mid(strInput, counter, 1)

        End If

    'else just paste the value
    Else
        Cells(17, i) = strInput
    End If

Next counter
```

Comment: Where did you get the mashed-up data? Are you **sure** that there isn't an invisible unicode character (e.g. zero-width space, null, etc) separating the dates? Atom data typically has a 'hard to find' delimiter character.

Comment: What should happen with the string `12/112/12`?  Is that 12/1 and 12/12, or is it 12/11 and 2/12?

Comment: Jeeped - This data is exported from an access db into an excel file, hope that helps.

Comment: YowE3K - m this data occurs on a week by week basis so it separate months should occur unless it's something like 12/311/1 = 12/31 and 1/1

Comment: Fix the access Select statement that collects the data. There also might be a vbLF separating the dates. Have you turned on word wrap in a  cell to see if there is? You are trying to repair data that was malformed in hte first place. **Fix the routine that collects the data** rather than trying to fix the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of the months within one cell's mashed up dates can be reasonably assumed to be the same then that could be used as a delimiter to split the mash-up and reassemble it.

```
Function splitMashUp(str As String, _
                     Optional splitchr As String = "/", _
                     Optional delim As String = ", ")
    Dim i As Long, tmp As Variant

    tmp = Split(str, Left(str, InStr(1, str, splitchr)))
    For i = LBound(tmp) + 1 To UBound(tmp)
        tmp(i) = Left(str, InStr(1, str, splitchr)) & tmp(i)
    Next i
    splitMashUp = Mid(Join(tmp, delim), Len(delim) + 1)
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: This could definitely work, but as this data is pulled on a weekly basis there may be some weeks that exist in two months such as 11/30 and 12/1, what would happen in that case?

Comment: Then you have [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) (click link for explanation). If you want to improve this code for other conditions (e.g. incrementing month (Oct to Nov) or resetting month (Dec - Jan) then have at it. It is beyond the scope of this site to code for every possible circumstance that could arise but if you make some effort, help should be forthcoming **on specific code questions**.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help. I will see what I can do about getting allowed access to that database. The files currently just come to me in excel form already.